# python program to monitor a file using file control

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a python program to monitor a file for any modification to the file by an external program.
I used the below sample program for monitoring the TEST.txt file but the sample program only work for directory and not for the file.
Any help appreciated to make it working for file.

```
import time
import fcntl
import os
import signal

FNAME = "/HOME/PRASAD/TEST.txt"

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "File %s modified" % (FNAME,)

signal.signal(signal.SIGIO, handler)
fd = os.open(FNAME,  os.O_RDONLY)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETSIG, 0)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_NOTIFY,
            fcntl.DN_MODIFY | fcntl.DN_CREATE | fcntl.DN_MULTISHOT)

while True:
    time.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify

Comment: Since i have some memory limitation in my target i cannot add any extra python package.I have to use only base python package and that is reason i choose the above sample

Comment: Well, your strategy does in fact only work on directories and there is no built-in inotify library for python. It may be possible to write one in pure python, but I can't imagine it being more memory efficient than the version written in C that I linked. You could call the `inotify` command via `subprocess`, but that's also likely worse on memory

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information.

Comment: "it only work" -- what means that exactly? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: maybe you could run own loop and check `os.stat(filename).st_mtime`. As I know `innotify` or `watchdog` if can't use system's function it runs loop which periodicaly calculate hash value for file and compare it with previous value - but it works fast for small files.

Comment: BTW: I found [inotify_simple](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/inotify_simple) which uses Linux library `inotify` and it has only 100 lines of code so you could copy all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `fcntl` to control folder in which is `TEST.txt` and when something changed in this folder then I would use other methods to check file `TEST.txt` - ie `os.stat(filename).st_mtime` or even full `os.stat(filename)`.

I don't know if I need all values `DN_` but without `DN_ATTRIB` it doesn't recognize `touch TEST.txt`

```
import time
import fcntl
import os
import signal

DNAME = "/HOME/PRASAD/"
FNAME = "/HOME/PRASAD/TEST.txt"

previous = os.stat(FNAME).st_mtime
#previous = os.stat(FNAME)

def handler(signum, frame):
    global previous
    
    print("DIR: {}".format(DNAME))
    
    current = os.stat(FNAME).st_mtime # <--- file
    #current = os.stat(FNAME)         # <--- file

    if current != previous:
        print("FILE: {} {}".format(FNAME, current))
        previous = current

signal.signal(signal.SIGIO, handler)
fd = os.open(DNAME, os.O_RDONLY)      # <--- directory
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETSIG, 0)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_NOTIFY,
            fcntl.DN_ACCESS |
            fcntl.DN_MODIFY |
            fcntl.DN_CREATE |
            fcntl.DN_DELETE |
            fcntl.DN_RENAME |
            fcntl.DN_ATTRIB |
            fcntl.DN_MULTISHOT)

while True:
    time.sleep(10000)
```